# Use of Java Enumerations/Iterators

Tags: java, vector, iterator, enumeration

I was just roaming through the API and it came to my attention that, Enumerations and Iterators aren't very useful interfaces.

Specifically I mean, instead of saying (for Vector v):

```
for (Enumeration<E> e = v.elements(); e.hasMoreElements();)
   System.out.println(e.nextElement());
```

We can easily say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
   System.out.println(v.elementAt(i));
```

What I wanted to know exactly is:

Are there any performance bonuses for using Enumerations/Iterators?

Has it provided you the ability to achieve something that cannot be achieved by the latter for loop?

Comment: What about if instead of a vector you have a linked list?  Think about what .elementAt(i) will do in that case.

Comment: So that might as well fall into performance, using a LinkedList in the first place, not a Vector (LinkedList is faster than Vector)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think iterators and enumerations are about performance; they're about better abstraction.

You don't need to know anything about the underlying data structure if you have an iterator.  That's why I think that interface is perfectly acceptable.  I don't agree with your statement that Iterator isn't a useful interface.  What methods would you add?

Comment: Well iterator has the remove() method, but then there is the removeElementAt() ?

Comment: But from what I understand from your answer, not having to know anything about the underlying data structure makes perfect sense especially if you are working collaboratively with others (using OOP) iterators would prove to be very useful. But nonetheless, if I am making a program on my own, I should have that knowledge of the data structure.

Comment: Enumeration is Java 1.0; Iterator came later.  Sometimes people learn from earlier mistakes - accept it and move on.  As for knowing the data structure, I'd argue that better abstraction and encapsulation is just as beneficial for you working alone as it is for larger groups.  None of your arguments are holding water with me.

Comment: @Jimmy: So you're saying that since you _can_ do something with one particular class when working on a project by yourself without using `Iterator` or whatever... that it isn't useful?

Comment: I guess more of the way you have when approaching programming. I am not one to make humongous programs (max 5 - 10 classes) so I usually know my programs inside out. But abstraction would be beneficial to the individual as well.

Comment: @CollinD Yes i did, which is why little knowledge is a bad thing ;)

Answer (score 7):

Not everything that has an `Iterator` is a random access `List`. A `Set`, for example, doesn't allow indexed access. A `LinkedList` allows it, but looping by index would have terrible performance.

Other things that aren't a `Collection` at all have `Iterator`s or can be represented as an `Iterator` as well. For example, one can represent an infinite sequence with an `Iterator`.

Having a simple, common interface that's used for iterating through things allows for methods that can operate on as wide a variety of objects as possible.

As an aside, both `Vector` and `Enumeration` are outdated and have basically been replaced in modern Java by `ArrayList` and `Iterator` respectively.

Comment: +1 for RandomAccess. Your best option is to use a for loop, as introduced in java 5. If the collection implements java.util.RandomAccess, the JVM may decide to loop by index (might be more efficient), otherwise it will use an iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the fact that Enumerators and Iterators are better at expressing what you are trying to do when you are trying to walk the values in a collection, and abstract away the details of the particular collection type as duffymo mentioned, the Iterator interface allows you to use the much more elegant `for` syntax such as:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String entry : list)
{
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Comment: Won't work with a tree structure or something you're written that's not part of the java.util Collections; a custom Iterator for breadth-first or depth-first search will.  Nice syntax, though.

Comment: @duffymo: It works with everything which implements `Iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe to modify the list while iterating using the Iterator.hasNext() method. If you simply check whether the index is less than the original size, you could run into problems...

Comment: Nice Call! EDIT: Just wrote a quick program, size changes along with the for loop. So you actually wouldn't run into problems.

Comment: @Jimmy: You would run in to problems with the index, not the size. If you remove the element at `i` and then advance to `i + 1`, you've just skipped the element that used to be at `i + 1`. Try making a list and looping through it calling `list.remove(i)` each iteration and see if the result is what you expect. =)

Comment: That answer is at best misleading: it's only save if you delete via the remove() method of the iterator and only if you delete in the same thread.
Otherwise you'll get a ConcurrentModificationException.

Answer (score 0):

iterator is about decouple and encapsulation. You don't need to care data structure difference, iterator has unique API to expose. As a result, client code doesn't need too much refactory even if collection changed. 
Before jdk 1.5, we use interface to manage some static final fields. You can compare them by writing some sample codes - (enum supports switch, e.g.)